Overpass around query on bridge centers
I have a Gpx track and I want to find the bridges it crosses.
I have try a simple request with my radius and coords:
(
wr["name"]["wikidata"]["man_made"="bridge"](around:radius,coords);
)->.bridge;
(.bridge;>>;)->.bridge;

.bridge out body;

It gives some great results but it also detects all bridges that are near quays when the track is going along quays.
So my idea was to do the around query on the center of bridges. However, I do not understand how I can do it, because using out center does give an output but I cannot get to use this output to do the around query.
EDIT: I have something that is almost working the idea is to keep only the bridges that have all nodes in an around query.
This is my new query, however, the if does not work, it returns all bridges and debugging with out count seems that the script is good, the if does not do what I want it to do. What are your inputs on this ?
[out:json];

// Définir la zone avec le bbox
()->.matching_bridges;
()->.first_and_last_total;
// Récupérer tous les ponts dans la zone et leurs centres
(
  way["name"]["wikidata"]["man_made"="bridge"](around:100,coords) -> .all_bridges;


// Get first and last nodes of each way
foreach .all_bridges -> .bridge (
()->.bridge_nodes;
()->.valid_nodes;
    // Extract  nodes
node(w.bridge)->.bridge_nodes;

  
(
  node.bridge_nodes (around:40,coords) -> .valid_nodes;

  
  .bridge_nodes out count;
  .valid_nodes out count;
  
  .bridge out tags;
  
  if (.valid_nodes.count(nodes) >= .bridge_nodes.count(nodes))
 {
   (.matching_bridges; .bridge;) -> .matching_bridges;
 }

)
  

// Output the matching bridges
.matching_bridges out center;

https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1Vlq
